# ASP.NET WEB API handling 2 relating tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

I am currently working with ASP.NET MVC WEB-API.

At first I create a controller using WEB-API and Entity Framework.
Using my `tbl_User`, calling it by .../api/User => it works all fine.
(no foreign-keys existing)

Doing the same for my `tbl_Entry` ( including `tbl_EntryType` ) and I get the following error:

```
<Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace/>
<InnerException>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
Type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.tbl_Entry_EAF4A2D5587BA15D1CE736067702C5D158ADFB6D6C49D43B66F64E14A4EBE8AC' with data contract name 'tbl_Entry_EAF4A2D5587BA15D1CE736067702C5D158ADFB6D6C49D43B66F64E14A4EBE8AC:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException
</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeAndVerifyType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean verifyKnownType, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiType(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle objectTypeHandle, Type objectType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle) at WriteArrayOftbl_EntryToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , CollectionDataContract ) at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeAndVerifyType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean verifyKnownType, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiTypeAtTopLevel(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle originalDeclaredTypeHandle, Type graphType) at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.WriteObject(XmlWriter writer, Object graph) at System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.<>c__DisplayClass7.<WriteToStreamAsync>b__6() at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously(Action action, CancellationToken token)
</StackTrace>
</InnerException>
</Error>
```

How do I fix this issue using `tbl_Entry` with `tbl_EntryType` included by a foreign key?

Comment: Does the tbl_Entry entity has a primary key?

Answer (score 0):

Its because your tables are referencing each other, so in essence it is creating a never-ending loop when trying to serialize. Depending on the complexity of your data, I would always recommend using ViewModels. It forces you to only expose the columns you wish to send and will fix the issue with serializing. If you are not going to be reusing your viewmodels, just return a new object with the data you need.

I am not sure about the structure of your app, but you could do something like this

```
    public object GetDealership(int id)
    {
        return Db.Dealerships.Find(id).Select(x => new { 
            x.SomeProperty, 
            x.RelationshipObject.SomeProperty 
        });
    }
```

Or using ViewModels (Recommend [Automapper](http://automapper.org/)), but for simplicities sake

```
    public ViewModel GetDealership(int id)
    {
        return Db.Dealerships.Find(id).Select(x => new ViewModel { 
            x.SomeProperty, 
            x.RelationshipObject.SomeProperty 
        });
    }
```